# What is "AllInternalsVisible" parameter of assembly:InternalsVisibleTo attribute?

Tags: c#, assemblies, friend, internalsvisibleto

My IntelliSense is coming up with a boolean named parameter "AllInternalsVisible=" in an `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyName")]` declaration.  Just position the cursor after  the second double-quote and hit Ctrl-space.  What is that - I cannot find any documentation on MSDN about that.  I am using VS2005 and .Net 2.0.

As a related topic, I'm doing some research on friend assemblies, and I thought that once you grant a friend assembly access to internals, the friend assembly has access to ALL internals and you can't really get granular about it.  Is that true, or is there a way (as suggested above) that you could grant a friend assembly access to some internal types/members but not all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.allinternalsvisible.aspx) Says:

> InternalsVisibleToAttribute..::.AllInternalsVisible
>   Property
>
> This API supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.
>
> This property is not implemented.

Answer (score 5):

In [Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.allinternalsvisible(v=vs.95).aspx), setting this to true means that everything with "friend" or "internal" visibility becomes visible to the other assembly. If it's not set, then only members with [FriendAccessAllowed](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/internalsvisibletoattribute.cs,387b29d3796e5353,references) become visible.

In desktop .NET, the property is not used since all internal members always become visible, as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft says:

> This API supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.
>
> This property is not implemented.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.allinternalsvisible.aspx